# generic interface handle both version

Tags: java, mongodb, generics, inheritance, interface

I have the following class:

```
public class Server extends ServerVersion1 {
   @Id
   private String id;
   public String getId() { return id; }
   public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }
}

public interface ServerRepository extends MongoRepository<Server,String> {

}
```

I created ServerVersion2, how can I write the a generic class to handle both version.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear - can you add more context?

Comment: add ServerVersion2 to existing Server collection(table) in mongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an abstract parent class that ServerVersion1 and ServerVersion2 will extend. Move code that is repeated in both subclasses to the abstract parent class. Now use a reference to this abstract parent class where ever in your code you want to handle objects of either ServerVersion class.

Comment: I can't access ServerVersion1, what can I do?

Comment: I see. I would then try to organize it as follows: Use your Server class as the parent class which contains everything relevant to both server versions. Then create 2 subclasses, something like ServerV1 and ServerV2. In your program use Server (or even ServerVersion1)  as the data type where you want to be able to handle ServerV1 or ServerV2 objects. Since these objects are instantiations of classes that extend Server, they pass the "Is-A" test and it should work.

Comment: Are you passing a collection as an argument to your calling method?

Comment: Can you post the method's current signature? I think you just need <? extends ServerV1> as the parameter's type.